# How to draw hardware-accelerated 3D graphics in the web browser?

Tags: 3d

I'd like to know if there is any way to draw hardware-accelerated 3D graphics in the web. What is the best technology for this? Java/Flash/Silverlight or maybe could it done with JavaScript? Maybe HTML5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be something interesting to you:

Google's O3D plugin

http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2009/04/google-releases-3d-graphics-plugin-for-browsers.ars

http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/

Comment: Looks cool, I'll check it out. Anyway: Is it ready to use for real games?

Comment: the community gallery has a bunch of examples, http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/docs/gallery.html there are a few games in there.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look at the [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/) standard. It is already implemented in nightly builds of Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Leopard and Snow Leopard. The [Learning WebGL Blog](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/) has a lot of useful information.

Comment: There's a WebGL-based game engine called CopperLicht that might be of interest: http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/index.html

The WebGL "community gallery" equivalent is here: http://khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions

It's worth noting that WebGL is quite literally a set of JavaScript bindings for OpenGL ES 2.0, so it's pretty low-level.  That gives you a lot more control than O3D, but means that you have to do more coding yourself.  There are also performance effects from coding more of the scene in JavaScript -- but then, WebGL doesn't require a plugin.  It's a tricky balance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I had an experience with [Virtools](http://www.3ds.com/products/3dvia/3dvia-virtools/).

Accelerated graphics worked, the technology was stable. The company provided good (but expensive) support. There's also large online community at theswapmeet.com.

The pricing was a little bit too high, though I don't know the current situation.